# Is there a way to silently extract a self extracting multipart rar files via commandline?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, rar

I have a multipart self extracting rar file;

```
setup.sfx.part1.exe
setup.sfx.part2.rar 
setup.sfx.part3.rar
```

Now when I try to extract it by starting the exe via commandline I get a nice screen where to extract things to:
[image]

Now my question is here: Is there any way via commandline (as I'm trying to run things automatically via batch job) to extract that file "silently", thus without this menu popping up?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like `unrar`. (There's a regular RAR archive inside the self-extracting stub.)

Some versions also support the `/s` option for silent mode.

Comment: Hmm unrar isn't defaultwise installed. Is there also the option to use the default windows zip/unzip commands there? or just unrar?